# Joint pmf of rolling two dice

Tags: probability

My probability textbook has the following exercise:

We roll two fair dice. Let $X_1$ be the smallest of the two outcomes and $X_2$ be the largest of the two. What is the joint mass function of $(X_1, X_2)$?

The book also has an answer guide that says the probability of getting $x_1=x_2$ (the two dice roll the same number) is 1/36 since "there is only one possible roll for this- $(x_1,x_1)$", but aren't there six ways to roll two of the same number? Why would the probability be 1/36 and not 6/36=1/6?

Comment: They're talking about the probability of getting a specific outcome $(x_1,x_2)$, for the random variables $(X_1,X_2)$. For each of the outcomes where $x_1 = x_2$, the probability of that outcome is $1/36$.

Comment: Yeap.  It's case sensitivity.  $\Bbb P(X_1=X_2)=1/6$ but they're talking about $\forall x_1=x_2:\Bbb P(X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2)=1/36$ .